# Created Button Click Event c#

Tags: c#, click

I have made a button using

```
Button buttonOk = new Button();
```

along with other code, how can I detect if the created button has been clicked?
And make it that if clicked the Form will close?

Comment: You need to attach event handler `buttonOk.Click += ...`

Comment: sorry for changing my question somewhat, but how can i do this so it will open a MessageBox

Comment: MessageBox.Show("some text");

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        // This button needs to exist on your form.
        myButton.Click += myButton_Click;
    }

    void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Message here");
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: doesn't work for me but thankyou

Comment: @FroodleStirling Does your button exist on your form? Instead of creating a new button in code, just use the button on your form. I updated my answer. Perhaps you can try that. Put the button on your form first.

Comment: it comes up with "a object reference is required"

Comment: @FroodleStirling Without coding with you, I think you just need to get a good book, or find examples online. This is really all there is to it. The only other suggestion I can think of is that you make sure your button is named the same (myButton, or whatever) on both your form and in the code.

Comment: @Bob Horn :where is the EventHandler?how it works?

Comment: To anyone else getting the " a object reference is required" error, try adding static to the method definition.  i.e.: `static void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`

Comment: It simply worked. thanks

Answer (score 10):

You need an event handler which will fire when the button is clicked.
Here is a quick way -

```
  var button = new Button();
  button.Text = "my button";

  this.Controls.Add(button);

  button.Click += (sender, args) =>
                       {
                           MessageBox.Show("Some stuff");
                           Close();
                       };
```

But it would be better to understand a bit more about buttons, events, etc.

If you use the visual studio UI to create a button and double click the button in design mode, this will create your event and hook it up for you. You can then go to the designer code (the default will be Form1.Designer.cs) where you will find the event:

```
 this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

You will also see a LOT of other information setup for the button, such as location, etc. - which will help you create one the way you want and will improve your understanding of creating UI elements.  E.g. a default button gives this on my 2012 machine:

```
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(128, 214);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.button1.Text = "button1";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
```

As for closing the Form, it is as easy as putting  Close(); within your event handler:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("some text");
       Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

if your button is inside your form class:

```
buttonOk.Click += new EventHandler(your_click_method);
```

(might not be exactly `EventHandler`)

and in your click method:

```
this.Close();
```

If you need to show a message box:

```
MessageBox.Show("test");
```

Comment: sorry for changing my question somewhat, but how can i do this so it will open a MessageBox

Answer (score 0):

Create the `Button` and add it to `Form.Controls` list to display it on your form:

```
Button buttonOk = new Button();
buttonOk.Location = new Point(295, 45);  //or what ever position you want it to give
buttonOk.Text = "OK"; //or what ever you want to write over it
buttonOk.Click += new EventHandler(buttonOk_Click);
this.Controls.Add(buttonOk); //here you add it to the Form's Controls list
```

Create the button click method here:

```
void buttonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("clicked");
            this.Close(); //all your choice to close it or remove this line
        }
```